# Prestashop database migration to newer version

Tags: database, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-1.4

Today we had to do a website upgrade from 1.4 to 1.7 included all the existing products. Due to time constraints we bought a commercial solution that charges over quantity. Now that the problem is solved I am thinking of working in a solution for the future should the need arise. What is the table relationship for orders, products and customers from 1.4 to 1.6 and then from 1.6 to 1.7? I have been searching for the documentation on the database structures but haven't been able to find it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: download the latest version of prestashop. go to the folder install\upgrade\sql and you get the steps to update the database from each version (every file form version A to version B is applied).

Comment: @sadlyblue you made the underrated best answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can purchase a migrate module and create a new test site, after that you transfer all of the data in the current site to the test site.
Ater you upgrade the current site to the latest version, you just re-transfer data from the test site to the live site. One module you can use many times :D
The cost of a migrate module cheaper than you hire a developer to work for you.
If you only want to transfer product, you just choose a free version module: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/

Or more, you can buy a premium module ( you can transfer: customer, product, order, categories... all of the data on your site): [Upgrade PrestaShop to 1.7](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/data-migration-backup/32298-prestashop-migrator-upgrade-prestashop-to-17.html)